# Equivalent of #[cfg(test)] for benchmarks?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

More specifically, I would like to have different constants for normal builds, test builds and benchmark builds:

```rust
#[cfg(not(test))]
const X: usize = 16;
#[cfg(test)]
const X: usize = 10;
#[cfg(benchmarking)] // <-- this doesn't work, and would conflict with not(test)
const X: usize = 100;
```

Comment: There's no option for benchmarking. All available options are listed [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#set-configuration-options). You can find [similar questions & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37679386/581190) where you can learn how to cope with features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a feature(benchmarking) section to your `Cargo.toml` file. The specifics can be found in the Cargo [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section).

```rust
[features]
benchmarking = []
```

After you add your feature, you need to write the specific benchmarking code for that feature in the code

```rust
.
.
#[cfg(feature = "benchmarking")]
{
    // count iterations check memory etc.
}
.
.
```

Then if you want to get these codes are added into compilation you need to set this feature while building like following:

```
cargo build --features "benchmarking"
```

For the detailed info you can check the [reference](https://www.worthe-it.co.za/programming/2018/11/18/compile-time-feature-flags-in-rust.html)

Comment: Can you also explain how to not have both definitions of `X` in scope? The version for `not(test)` will be defined at the same time as `benchmarking`.

Comment: The version for `not(test)` will not be defined at the same time as `benchmarking`. Ideally you should not need to change the behavior of the code to benchmark. It should only `trace/profile` the execution without changing the behavior.

Comment: I only suggested to add that because the comment in OP's says they expect a problem with that conflict. `#[cfg(benchmarking)]` _must_ conflict with either `#[cfg(test)]`  or `#[cfg(not(test))]`.