# Conditional compilation for 'nightly' vs 'stable' Rust or compiler version

Tags: rust

I am using some Rust unstable features, but I still want to be able to compile a reduced version of my library with stable Rust.  I am happy to only include those unstable features when the compiler supports them, and exclude them when they are not supported.

I thought it would be easy to achieve this goal using conditional compilation like `#[cfg(rust_version = "nightly")]`, but it seems like 'stable' vs 'nightly' are not [cfg options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/conditional-compilation.html).

How do you guys perform conditional compilation based on 'stable' vs 'nightly', or based on the compiler version?

Comment: You may also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674758/ignore-benchmarks-when-using-stable-beta for similar solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend creating a [feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) for your nightly-only code that is disabled by default, for example

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[features]
default = []
nightly-features = []
```

Since the `nightly-features` feature is not default, compilation with the stable toolchain works out of the box. You can use [attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) `#[cfg(feature = "nightly-features")]` and `#[cfg(not(feature = "nightly-features"))]` to include or exclude code from nightly-specialized versions. This method has the added benefit of allowing testing of the nightly features independently of the compiler (i.e. answer the question: did the compiler break my code, or does code enabled by `nightly-features` contain bugs?).

##### Despite the risks, I want to enable nightly features automatically

Use [build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html), sometimes called `build.rs` in addition to the nightly feature described above. (note: the following should NEVER be used in a library, otherwise switching compilers could become a breaking change. prefer the solution explained above)

`build.rs` (goes in package root)

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let rust_toolchain = env::var("RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN").unwrap();
    if rust_toolchain.starts_with("stable") {
        // do nothing
    } else if rust_toolchain.starts_with("nightly") {
        //enable the 'nightly-features' feature flag
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=feature=\"nightly-features\"");
    } else {
        panic!("Unexpected value for rustc toolchain")
    }
}
```

this build script checks the toolchain environment variable set by [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) (some rust installations do not use rustup) and enables the nightly feature flag if the compiler is nightly.

`src/main.rs`

```rust
fn main() {
    #[cfg(feature = "nightly-features")]
    println!("Hello, nightly!");
    #[cfg(not(feature = "nightly-features"))]
    println!("Hello, stable!");
}
```

now, running

```
➜  cargo +stable run      
Hello, stable!
➜  cargo +nightly run
Hello, nightly!
```

##### Is it possible to turn this feature off when build.rs turns it on?

As far as I can tell, no. Running `cargo +nightly run --no-default-features` leaves the feature on, due to how cargo passes flags to rustc. A programmer could create a specific environmental variable that build.rs checks for to skip the automatic version detection, but that is more complicated than the alternative with no build script - `cargo build --features=nightly-features`

##### Crate alternative

Instead of the proposed solution, you can use the [rustversion](https://crates.io/crates/rustversion) crate, which works in a very similar way (but parses the output of `rustc --version`).

```rust
fn main() {
    #[rustversion(nightly)]
    println!("Hello, nightly!");
    #[rustversion::not(nightly)]
    println!("Hello, stable! (or beta)");
}
```